# How do I append certain elements in Json dictionary based on the ID?

Tags: python

I've been working on this code in relation to a bigger project that will get the users name, and based on the name it will display that persons past logged weight using Tkinter with Python.  I'm just trying to get this example code I've made to work where it will get the persons name and store their weight according to their name.  Right now it creates a new ID of the same person instead of adding the weight to the existing ID.  How Can I get it to not add an ID if it already exists but just add the weight to the existing ID?

```
import json
ID = raw_input('What is your name?')
weight = raw_input('What is your weight?')
data = {'People': [{'name': ID, 'weight':weight}]}

with open('data.json', 'a+') as outfile:
    storage = data 
    storage({'weight': weight})
    json.dump(storage, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

it currently reads:

```
{
    "People": [
        {
            "name": "Bob", 
            "weight": "124"
        }
    ]
}{
    "People": [
        {
            "name": "Jerry", 
            "weight": "111"
        }
    ]
}{
    "People": [
        {
            "name": "Bob", 
            "weight": "130"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to get it into a format as close to the below code as I can get:

```
}{
    "People": [
        {
            "name": "Jerry", 
            "weight": "111"
        }
    ]
}{
    "People": [
        {
            "name": "Bob", 
            "weight": "130", "124"
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I going about this wrong? I was hoping to read out the file for only specific the ID entered and show the existing weights after logging the new one. For example, all of "Bob's" weight would show after the code ran. I'm pretty new to json so if this there is a more efficient way, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to make your `data.json` file contain valid json content, I suggest you can make your `data.json` to be like:

```
{
    "People": [
        {
            "name": "Bob", 
            "weight": [
                "124", 
                "130"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Jerry", 
            "weight": [
                "111"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Second, you can open the json file and load as dictionary, after that you can manipulate on it. If find the `name` and append `weight` into a list, if new name, add the whole `name` and `weight`. below is the code:

```
import json
ID = raw_input('What is your name?')
weight = raw_input('What is your weight?')
data = {'People': [{'name': ID, 'weight':[weight]}]}

with open('data.json') as outfile_r:
    try:
        source_data = json.load(outfile_r)
        new_name = True
        for ppl in source_data['People']:
            if ppl['name']==ID:
                ppl['weight'].append(weight)
                new_name = False
        if new_name:
            source_data['People'].append({'name': ID, 'weight':[weight]})
        storage = source_data
    except:
        storage = data
with open('data.json','w') as outfile_w:
    json.dump(storage, outfile_w, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot more sense, still getting to know json and python

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just appending it try loading the data first, checking to see if that user is already there, then adding and saving the data.

```
import json
ID = raw_input('What is your name?')
weight = raw_input('What is your weight?')
data = {'People': [{'name': ID, 'weight':weight}]}

with open('data.json', 'w+') as outfile:
    parsed_json = json.loads(outfile)
    ppl = parsed_json['People']
    try: 
        person = ppl[ID]
        person['weight'] = weight
    except:
        ppl += { "name": ID, "weight": weight }
    storage(ppl)
    json.dump(storage, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```